# Tell me if invalid SQL login, but continue with script... How?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I want my script to tell me, if the login to the database has failed with a custom response.write() and then continue with my script. Is this possible?

Say I have this:

```
      set conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")

      dsn = "Provider = sqloledb; Data Source = XX; Initial Catalog = XX; User Id = XX; Password = XX
      conn.connectiontimeout = 300
      conn.commandtimeout = 300

      if conn.state = 0 then
        conn.open dsn
      end if
```

If the conn couldn't be opened because of bad Data Source, User Id or Password, then I want it write me a message with response.write() and then CONTINUE with the rest of the script, or else it should do my sql-actions AND THEN continue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
on error resume next
conn.open dsn
if err.number <> 0 then
   response.write "connection string was bad"
else
   ' other SQL activity here
end if
on error goto 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `On Error Resume Next`

This page talks about handling connection errors and gives a pretty good example of what you are talking about.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/debugginganderrorhandling/article.php/c19557/ASP-and-the-Error-Handler.htm